# Make "singing" tag a synonym of "voice" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently there are 4 questions tagged [voice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice) and 1 question tagged [singing](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singing). I think it would make sense to merge them.

Comment: The question must have been retagged.  I don't see [singing] existing right now, so this may have resolved itself.  If the tag comes back a synonym could be proposed then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree.  While, as with all tags, it is possible to distinguish them, I don't think they will end up being used in different senses (at least not consistently).  And if they're going to be used synonymously, they should be tag synonyms.